# excel: if cell contains multiple criteria then return multiple criteria, nestled?

Tags: excel, search, match, criteria

I have 4 criteria lists that look like this:

```
A         B
Name      Category
Name      Category
Name      Category
```

And a MasterList like this:

```
A             B
stuffNAME     Category
NAMEstuff     Category
NAME          Category
```

I would like to know if there is a formula that can search through each criteria list based on the MasterlistA column for "NAME" and return the appropriate "Category" in MasterlistB.

As an example:
I'm looking to return MasterlistB based on MasterlistA

Criteria List:

```
A         B
NBC       NBCU
Disney    ABC
```

Masterlist:

```
A                  B   
NYC NBC 20998      NBCU
NJ2987 NBC         NBCU
Disney Florida99   ABC
```

I'm simplifying, but in reality the criteria lists all refer to different masterlist columns as well. Trying to get the matching/searching part down first.

Comment: You need a method to determine what is "stuff", and what is "NAME". ie: is the NAME always the last word in a cell? Is it always 3 characters long after the first " "?

Comment: @grade-eh-bacon

i dont think that's possible for my dataset. The "stuff" is random and not uniform in any way. I tried thinking through VLOOKUPS and I came to the conclusion that it probably isn't the answer. I was wondering if excel can do a simultaneous search/match or something, or since the term i'm using as my reference is the one with extra "stuff" it's just not possible?

Comment: See the further edit to my question - you can create helper columns on your category lists, to use a wildcard search against your Master list; you can then use your Master list to do a vlookup against this newly created column in each of your category lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a setup as shown in @ScottCraner 's answer:

[image: Scott Craner data setup]

In cell E1 and copied down:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,1/COUNTIF(D1,"*"&$A$1:$A$2&"*"),$B$1:$B$2),"No Match")
```

This is a regular formula and does not require array entry.

Answer (score 1):

**You can do this using VLOOKUP, nested with the IFERROR statement**.

I am assuming each table is starting on A1, in sheets called Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, and Sheet4. You may need to adjust references to point to appropriate tables.

The basic formula to find the category which matches your name, is simply [assuming your search term is on a new sheet on A1, let's say Sheet5, with the rest of your final data table]:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,'Sheet1'!A:B,2,0)
```

This simply takes the value in A1 [the search term], tries to find it in column A of sheet 1, and if it does find it, takes the first matching row, and returns the value on the 2nd column in [column B, with the category].

If that fails, you simply put that inside of IFERROR, which attempts to calculate something, and if it creates an error, returns something else, like so:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,'Sheet1'!A:B,2,0),"NO MATCH FOUND")
```

Now to use the IFERRORS to first attempt to find a match on Sheet1, then Sheet2, etc., put the following:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,'Sheet1'!A:B,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,'Sheet2'!A:B,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,'Sheet3'!A:B,2,0),VLOOKUP(A1,'Sheet4'!A:B,2,0))))
```

**To search for only a partial match, you can use the following**:

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&A1&"*",'Sheet1'!A:B,2,0)
```

The "*" act like wildcards, and if they are included in front of and behind your search term [in this case, A1], then anything that contains your search term, regardless of its position in a cell, will be considered a match. You can replace A1 in all of my above formulas with this revised wildcard match to check for partial matches in any of your sheets.

**To search a list of items, which exactly match a** *part* **of your search term**

You could probably do this with an array formula, but because you have multiple data tables, I think the easiest solution is to use a helper column next to each of those tables, to create a unique ID which actually matches to your Master List. ie:

On Sheet1 [and all other category sheets], insert a new column in between A & B; this column will trace back from column A, to match a Name from your Master List on Sheet5, like so [starting in B1 & copied down]:

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&A1&"*", 'Sheet5'!A:A, 1, 0)
```

Your revised formula in your master sheet would now look like this:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,'Sheet1'!B:C,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,'Sheet2'!B:C,2,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,'Sheet3'!B:C,2,0),VLOOKUP(A1,'Sheet4'!B:C,2,0))))
```

Comment: Hi, I just edited my post cause I realized I wasn't being clear enough. I don't think I can use VLOOKUP cause I'm searching for part of a string. Correct me if I'm wrong. @grade-eh-bacon

Comment: @saya This can be done - see my revised edit; you will need to replace A1 in my above formulas with "*"&A1&"*" to include partial matches.

Comment: @grade-eh-bacon

i tried this before, but the problem i ran into was that my search term, masterlistA, was the set that contained extra words and I couldn't think of a way around it. So the item i'm referencing is "stuffNAMEstuff" , but I want it to return something just based on just the "NAME" part.

Comment: @saya How can you tell what the "stuff" is and what the "NAME" is? This is a completely different question...

Comment: @grade-eh-bacon

i guess even after editing its still not clear. there's no way of telling what that "stuff" is and its always different. as an example. say masterlist columnA is "RadioNYC NBC" I am trying to pinpoint that NBC part which would be on the criteria list as "NBC" and return the corresponding "Category." Does that make sense? I'll try to make my post a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than placing the four lists side-by-side like:

[image]

Stack them on top of each other like:

[image]

The its as simple as:

```
=VLOOKUP("David",A1:B12,2)
```

Comment: i can't stack these lists, because there is an order of how i want category to be returned. i didn't mention for simplicity, but i would be referencing different masterlist columns and it has to return category based on list 1 match first, then list 2. But I don't think vlookup works in general.

Comment: @saya Take another look at what Gary has done with the stacking - he put the most important list at the top, then the 2nd most important, then 3rd, then 4th. When VLOOKUP finds mutiple matches, it always chooses the highest one in order. So your special ordering would work. As for how to use VLOOKUP given that your Master List values includes garbage characters, see the edit to my answer above, or Scott's method. This would avoid the simplicity of all of the "IFERROR" statements required. If you wanted to visually separate your list using Gary's method, you could always insert subheader rows.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the basic formula to get what you want:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$2,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$2)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*" & $A$1:$A$2 & "*",D1))),1))
```

if you have 2010 or later.  If you have 2007 and earlier than you will need to use the following array formula:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$2,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*" & $A$1:$A$2 & "*",D1)),ROW($1:$2)),1))
```

It being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

In the picture, the first formula is Column F, the second in Column E

[image]

You will need to add nested IFERROR() Functions for the various sheets.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$2,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$2)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*" & Sheet1!$A$1:$A$2 & "*",A1))),1)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$2,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$2)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*" & Sheet2!$A$1:$A$2 & "*",A1))),1)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet3!$B$1:$B$2,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$2)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*" & Sheet3!$A$1:$A$2 & "*",A1))),1)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet4!$B$1:$B$2,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$2)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*" & Sheet4!$A$1:$A$2 & "*",A1))),1)),"NOT HERE"))))
```

Comment: @tigeravatar you might as well post it in an answer.  I like it.